# Custom union type narrowing

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

First, `mypy` has [builtin capabilities](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#union-types) of narrowing down `Union` into more specific types using `isinstance`.
There's also a special case for `Optional` type.

Is there any way to make `mypy` treat my custom types like `Optional`.
E.g. say I have this `UnsupportedT` type:

```
class UnsupportedT:
    def __bool__(self) -> Literal[False]:
        return False


def inc(n: int) -> int:
    return n + 1


value: Union[UnsupportedT, None, int] = UnsupportedT()
if value:
    print(inc(value))
```

Then `mypy` will complain about:

```
main.py:34: error: Argument 1 to "inc" has incompatible type "Union[UnsupportedT, int]"; expected "int"
```

Using `isinstance` all the time is too verbose and restricts coding style too much. E.g. I could opt to use walrus operator as well.

So is there a way to make `mypy` undestand that `if value` just narrowed down the type of `value` to `int`?
Maybe `mypy` plugin is the way to go?
If so, how would I approach the problem with the plugin?

Comment: You set `value = UnsupportedT()` but you want mypy to think it's an `int`...? Can you clarify?

Comment: Sure :)
That's just a demo and I want `mypy` to understand that in this code branch `value` will be an `int`:

    if value:
        print(inc(value))

Comment: This is an open feature request [in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8692). If you want to take a stab at creating a PR for this, one approach you can take is to override the `can_be_true_default` and `can_be_false_default` methods for Instance in [mypy/types.py](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/types.py) so they check for the existence of a `__bool__` method with a Literal return type.